# Ajax form doesn't load files

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, file, upload

I have an Ajax form, which loads several files; the problem is that `Request.Files` is always empty. I couldn't find anything about it, so here it is.

```
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Manage", FormMethod.Post,
    new AjaxOptions{ OnComplete = "OnSaveEditSuccess" },
    new { enctype="multipart/form-data", id = "form_Edit", name = "form_Edit" }))
{%>
    /* ... */
    <input type="file" id="CCTranscripts_fileId" name="CCTranscripts_fileId" 
        onchange="ValidateUploadFile('CCTranscripts_file', this.value);" />
    /* ... */
<% } %> <%-- end form --%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload files using an AJAX Form. In order to upload files you need to use a normal `Html.BeginForm`. This is because when an AJAX request is sent the `multipart/form-data` is no longer respected. Also using javascript you cannot access the file contents in order to send it to the server. There are some plugins which allow you to achieve this. For example the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) supports [AJAX uploads](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) by generating a hidden iframe. [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is another popular plugin which uses Flash.

Comment: My form is in a modal dialog, so I can't go back to a Html.BeginForm; the whole point was to perform the edit without a postback. We don't use jQuery form, so I'll give uploadify a try.

Comment: Does that means, that if I try to upload a file with a common form, launching a JavaScript function which uses xmlhttp and send a POST with it, i won't be able to do it? =(